# Fingerprint reader in HP dv7

Tags: 12.10, fingerprint-reader

I am running Ubuntu 12.10, I recently installed "fingerprint gui 1.05~pre2" on my HP dv7 notebook that has a built in fingerprint scanner.  When launched fingerprint gui says "No Device Found".  What linux command do I use to try and find the technical information about my fingerprint scanner.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that no driver for your fingerprint reader is installed.
Use the console and type 'lspci' and 'lsusb' to find out the type of fingerprint reader installed (look for 'fingerprint reader' or something similar in both outputs). Following that you can google for a linux driver for this type of reader to find out which package has to be installed. Then the GUI should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me find my direction.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the Validity scanners used in dv7 laptops (such as mine) are unsupported by the libfprint drivers. See here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/Unsupported%20devices - it specifically mentions 138a:0001, but the situation is the same for mine (138a:0018).

So I suppose the answer is that there isn't really a solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some of the comments here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-get-your-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+d0od+%28OMG!+Ubuntu!%29

Some had not recognized devices and got it to work, so maybe this works for you as well. I have not gone into this since my fingerprint reader was recognized out of the box...